# my Boolean is set to true when its specified as false for some reason

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

i am trying to do like a console where you can change a variable by saying yes or no, and for some reason one of my Boolean (auto) variables are being set to true even when it should be defaulted to false
here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Digital {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean ignite = false;
        boolean heatup = false;
        boolean dispose = false;
        boolean alertwick = false;
        boolean auto = false;

        boolean candlewick = false;
        boolean off = false;
        boolean ready = false;
        boolean swich = false;

        System.out.println("consol- set circumstances of the candle");
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("is the switch on?");

        String consolswich = myObj.nextLine();

        if (consolswich.equals("yes")) {

            swich = true;
        } else {


        }



        System.out.println("is the candle ready?(in auto)");

        String consolready = myObj.nextLine();
        if (consolready.equals("yes")) {
            ready = true;
        } else {


        }
        System.out.println("is auto on?");

        String consolau = myObj.nextLine();
        if (consolau.equals("yes")) {
            auto = !auto;
        } else {


        }
        System.out.println("are there any wicks left?");
        String consolwick = myObj.nextLine();
        if (consolwick.equals("yes")) {
            candlewick = true;
        } else {


        }

        System.out.println("how long is the candlewick?(whole number, cm)");
        int consollength = myObj.nextInt();
        int candleheight = consollength;




        if (auto = true) {
            System.out.println("ballin");


            if ((swich = true) && (auto = false)) {
                if (candleheight < 1) {
                    dispose = true;
                    System.out.println("candlewick disposed");
                }
                if (candlewick = false) {
                    alertwick = true;
                    System.out.println("user as been alerted to the lack of candlewicks");


                } else {
                    heatup = true;
                    System.out.println("the candle has been formed and then ignited");

                }

            } else {
                System.out.println("nothing happened/error");
            }
        } else {
            while (auto = true) {

                if (ready = true)

                {
                    ignite = true;
                    System.out.println("the candle has been lit");
                    break;

                } else {
                    if (candleheight == 0) {
                        dispose = true;
                        System.out.println("candlewick has been disposed of");
                    }
                    if (candlewick = false) {
                        alertwick = true;
                        System.out.println("user has been alerted to the lack of candlewicks");
                        break;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("the candle has been formed");
                        ready = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }




    }
}
```

i have tried different ways of changing the boolean, and i know all the other parts work, the other variables work when auto is removed, but it is a necessary part of the program so i cant remove it

Comment: HI, you are using value assignment `auto = true` instead of comparation `auto == true` in `if` and `while`. It is desirable to use boolean values in this way `if(auto)`

Comment: i have tried this and it worked, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the comparison `==` in your `while()` and `if()` statements since you would like to compare two variables.

The operator `=` is for assignment and will set the value of the variable on the left to the value of the right.

---

Another improvement to consider but consider using using the boolean variables directly instead of comparing to `true` and `false`. For example, try converting:

```
if ((swich = true) && (auto = false)) {
    // more code
}
```

to

```
if(switch && !auto){
    // more code
}
```

This will make it much clearer what the purpose of that `if()` statement is.